# MediaCapture Effect failed by "Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation."

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I am using MediaCapture(Windows.Media.Capture) class to add some effects to webcam input frames. For applying effects, I am working with [Win2D](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D) library. After I clear and re-apply effects like below code few times, the exception is raised and the web cam doesn't work.

The MediaCapture's Failed event shows arguments like this :

```
MediaCaptureFailedEventArgs
Code : 2147942414
Message : "Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation."
```

However, The performance counter in Task manager shows sufficient memory amount to use.

```
//Reset Effect Method
private async Task ApplyAllEffects()
{
  await ClearAllEffects();
  await ApplyRemoveGreenEffect();
}
```

```
//Clear All Effects Method
private async Task ClearAllEffects()
{
  //_previewMediaCapture is a MediaCapture object
  if (_previewMediaCapture == null) return;
  await _previewMediaCapture.ClearEffectsAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
}

//Add Effect Method
private async Task ApplyRemoveGreenEffect()
{
  if (_previewMediaCapture == null) return;

  var properties = new PropertySet();
  properties[nameof(RemoveGreenMediaExtension.Value)] = (float)Preferences.RemoveGreen;

  var definition = new VideoEffectDefinition(typeof(RemoveGreenVideoEffect).FullName, properties);

  await _previewMediaCapture.AddVideoEffectAsync(definition, MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
}
```

I checked the program and code of [Win2d Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D-Samples/) offered by MS.
It has same problem too.
There's no way to avoid this problem?

Comment: I have tested with Win2D camera effect scenario, and it works well, So, I could not reproduce your issue, Could you share more info about your device such as os version camera production,

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have got something for the problem. First, Task Manager says GPU memory's leaking... Second, Before applying MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync() or some IBasicVideoEffect with new parameters, I called MediaCapture.Dispose() for some cleaning. It has caused this problem! When I remove it and run, it works well without any GPU memory leak. However, I don't know why it happened still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess why this things are happened.

Before I initialize the MediaCapture object and apply Win2D effects to it, I used MJPG codec for cam's by calling [MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.setmediastreampropertiesasync) method.

It's supported one by my web cam(Logitech C920) for 30fps in 1080p.
It caused GPU Memory leaks. When I use raw(YUV) codec or NV12 codec for input frames, GPU memory leak isn't happend.

I think, MJPG encoding process is added to cam's graphical pipe-line and by some reasons with it that pipe-line can't be released properly.